# Get vim to write files to Program Files in Windows

Tags: windows, vim

When I create and open a file with vim, i.e. "vim new.txt" it works fine in a folder like my desktop. However, when I am in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\ftplugin\" and I try to create a file with "vim python.vim" or "vim new.txt", vim opens and appears to work fine, but after I save the file and exit vim, it does not exist in the folder. HOWEVER, if I type "vim python.vim" again to re-open the (apparently non-existent) file, vim comes up happily right where I left off in the file that doesn't exist. Can someone tell me what is going on and how to fix it?

Edit: A search of my filesystem for the nonexistent files shows them to in "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\ftplugin" instead of the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\ftplugin\" from which they were created. Any ideas why, though, and how to make this not happen?

Comment: Does `:pwd` or `:echo expand('%:p')` give a helpful clue?

Comment: These commands both show the current directory as "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\ftplugin\", even though, as my edit shows, the files are not in fact there but somewhere else.

Comment: May be the second path in `Edit` is a shortcut to the first one.

Comment: That is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're experiencing is the *file system redirection* of the `%ProgramFiles%` location (the same is done for the Windows system files under `%WINDIR%`), because you're not running under an *elevated account*. Starting with Windows Vista, when *User Account Control* (UAC) is enabled, you cannot directly access system files and installed applications any more (for security reasons). Windows detects software installers and prompts you to elevate the account, but it doesn't detect Vim's accesses, and (for backward compatibility) redirects those accesses to the *VirtualStore*.

There are several ways around this:

- Turn off UAC (bad idea, lower security)
- Start an elevated instance of GVIM (search for gvim in the Start Menu, and select with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>), and edit with that.
- Avoid the problem by creating a `vimfiles` directory at `%HOME%` (`C:\Users\Daniel` for you) instead of `$VIM/vimfiles` and put your config there (see `:help vimrc`).